# Is it a good practice to use acronyms of words in slug urls for seo?

Tags: url, seo, slug

I have to write a slug url for an article where the title is `United States of America`. As a good practice for seo, should I leave as it is for the slug url (`united-states-of-america`) or `USA` to shorten?

Answer (score -1):

First question is : 
Does your users navigate by manual update of URL?

If yes : you should use Title

If No : The limit of URL lenght is 2000 characters. 
Do you think that your final URL will increase this limit ?

If yes : You should use USA (you URL will be shorter)
If No : You should use Title

Finally, for SEO you should use the title of your article. An URL with Title of article is more friendly for users ;-)